# Latex: Figure is too large for PDF

Tags: graphics, scaling

I am a graduate student working on a research paper. I am using WinEdit 8.1.  I am new to latex but I am almost finished with the paper.     I am have issue inserting a picture into the document. Whenever I put it in latex, it makes the picture too large in the created PDF document.

The following is my latex code

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{centering}
  \includegraphics{MicrofabSteps}
  \caption[Proposed Micro-fabrication Steps]{}
  \label{fig:Microfabrication Steps}
  \end{centering}
\end{figure}
```

How can i possible tell latex to make the picture "smaller" so that it does not show up so large in the pdf output file.

Comment: This will likely get migrated; in case it doesn't, use `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]`. Other options include `scale=0.3` to manually control sizing, and specifying width in, say, centimeters with `width=3cm`, or `\textwidth` instead of `\linewidth` for full-page width.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this:

`\includegraphics[width = 16cm, height = 9cm]{MicrofabSteps}`

or

`\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{MicrofabSteps}`

width and height can be also entered in inches, mm all units that tex supports, and scale is i suppose any number. Numbers smaller than one make it smaller, numbers larger than one make it bigger, just saying.

Comment: Consider using relative lengths, like `\linewidth` or `\textwidth`, rather than fixed lengths like `16cm`. Also consider using `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`, which allows you to set `\includegraphics[max width=\linewidth]{<figure>}` that would only *shrink* `<figure>`, if needed.

Comment: Don't use width and height or it will distort the figure, or use keepaspectratio, but normally just specify one.